# Get items of HashMap based on an Calendar Month key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap :

```
HashMap<Integer, Person> map
```

The key is actually the month (int) I get from a Calendar.MONTH. It means it goes from 0 to 11 and each month has a Object of type Person associated.

Assuming we are in February, what I would like to do is getting all Person of the past 4 months but I can't find a way to do this. Moreover we have to assume that a month could be missing in the map so in such a case I will consider the Person of this month as a "0" or null or whatever but I don't want to "skip" it.

Can anyone help me to figure it this out ? I have no idea of a "proper" way to achieve this.

Comment: You have no code for your question, put some.

Comment: Hint: why do you think you need a map, when you the low-level concept of representing months as 0-based integers anyway? What I mean: if you would be using a class that really models months, then a map would make sense. But when you know that you have 0 to 11 keys; why aren't you using a simple array/list.

Comment: I have nothing more to put because as I said I have no idea of how to start :/

Comment: I think I need a map because for each month there is a Person which is associated. Later, I'll need to get the Person of Decembre and so on.. I may be wrong but this is what seems the more practical to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you would need to do:

1. Get current month from a Calendar instance.  The month is from 0 to 11.
2. Create a for loop that loops 4 times
3. Within the loop, get the Person for the current month from the Map.  Add the Person to a List.
4. Within the loop, subtract one month from the current month.  If the current month is less than zero, add 12 to the current month.
5. Your list will contain 4 Person objects, or null if that's what the Map returned.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the step 4. Can you explain this a little bit ?

Comment: The current month is an int.  Subtract one from the current month.  Test the result with an if statement.  The test is if the current month is less than zero (negative).  A negative month is in the prior year.  Add 12 to the current month if it is negative, to get it back in the range of 0 - 11.

Comment: Ok I think I got it now ! I'll try to do this